# How can I fetch an attribute from a string in javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, json

I have below string in my javascript variable which is returned from the controller as a wrapper value. I need to fetch the value of "Tasks" attribute from the javascript string variable on my vf page. Can anyone provide me any javascript method that can parse its value?

```
 var taskDetails = "DetailsList:[resources={}, tasks={a0e28000006wwRcAWQ=FormListItem:[id=a0e28000006wwRcAAI, name=Survey1, status=Published, surveyId=a0f28000005xYItAAM], a0e28000006wzy6AAA=FormListItem:[id=a0e28000006wzy6ADE, name=CLONE 1 Survey1, status=Published, surveyId=a0f28000005xYLsAAM], a0e28000006x0w6AAA=FormListItem:[id=a0e28000006x0w6DEA, name=CLONE 1 CLONE 1 Survey1, status=Closed, surveyId=a0f28000005xYNtAAM], a0e28000006xxpAAAQ=FormListItem:[id=a0e28000006xxpFGAQ, name=PPI Survey, status=Draft, surveyId=a0f2800000602NEAAY], a0e28000006xzMjAAI=FormListItem:[id=a0e28000006xzMDFAI, name=CLONE 1 Survey1, status=Published, surveyId=a0f28000005xYLsAAM], a0e28000007Lmd8AAC=FormListItem:[id=a0e28000007LmdWQAC, name=Draft Survey, status=Draft, surveyId=a0f28000006Iu2UAAS]}]";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to parse that awkward to parse string, it makes more sense to output the data in a format that is easy to parse in JavaScript and that format is JSON.

So in the Apex code add a method somewhere:

```
public String getTaskDetailsJson() {
    // Its this easy to generate JSON in Apex
    return JSON.serialize(taskDetails);
}
```

and output that into a JavaScript variable in the Visualforce page (here in the simplest form):

```
var taskDetails = {!taskDetailsJson};
```

Then in your JavaScript you will be able to use simple JavaScript property or array references to directly access the data.